# Little o-notation and Taylor exapnsion

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, taylor-expansion

consider a differentiable function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ that attains a global minimum at $x$. Consider the following limiting direction with $t_k \to 0$ and $z_k \to x$ for $k \to \infty$

$$d = \lim_{{k \to \infty}} \frac{{z_k - x}}{{t_k}}$$

This means:

$$ z_k = x + t_k d + o\left(t_k \right)
$$

Since in $x$ is a global minimum, we have:

$$ 0 \leq \frac{1}{t_k} (f(z_k
) - f(x)) = \frac{1}{t_k} \nabla f(x)^\top t_kd + \frac{1}{t_k} o(t_k)$$

My question is why the last term with the o notation $ \frac{1}{t_k} o(t_k)$ does not change? Is the last equality some kind of Taylor expansion and the remainder is somehow merged into the o-term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Take into account that $o(\cdot)$ is a qualitative notation, so $o(\cdot)+o(\cdot)=o(\cdot)$ and $o(k(\cdot))=o(\cdot)$ etc.

By Taylor expansion with remainder in the form of Peano,
$$
f(z_k)-f(x)=\nabla f(x)^T(z_k-x)+o(z_k-x)=\nabla f(x)^T(z_k-x)+o(t_k)
$$
But you also have
$$
\nabla f(x)^T(z_k-x)=\nabla f(x)^Tt_kd+\nabla f(x)^To(t_k)=\nabla f(x)^Tt_kd+o(t_k).
$$
Putting everything together and dividing throughout by $t_k$  you get what you need.

Comment: Thank you. I do not get how we aggregate the difference of vectors and a scalar into the same little o notation: Why does the following hold for example: $$ o(z_k-x) = o(t_k)$$

Comment: $z_k-x=t_kd$ is a vector. $o(z_k-x) =o(t_kd)$ is a scalar function of the vector, approaching zero faster than the magnitude of the vector, $\|t_kd\|=t_k\|d\|$. But $\|d\|$ is fixed while $t_k\to 0$, so the given scalar approaches zero faster than $t_k$, thus being a $o(t_k)$.

Comment: Thank you. Last question: Why does this then go to 0: $ \frac{1}{t_k} o(t_k)$

Comment: You just divide throughout by $t_k$.

Comment: I do not know why I have to do that?

Comment: This computation must be part of the proof of some fact...